# Using Form Authentiucation when Browser Cookie settings is disbled

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking for a solution, or a good article how to maintain user information when cookie option is disabled in browser.

Any link or code how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How do you think any session-specific information will get from the browser to you if the client doesn't send any information?

The traditional way would be to pass a session identifier in GET and POST requests, though that suffers from serious security risks. Best to just tell the client they need to allow session cookies.

(I could think of a more roundabout way of using AJAX and client-side storage to request session-specific bits of data from the client's runtime, but it'd all boil down to URL parameters in a GET/POST request.)